# React change only clicked button text [Looped]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I click the button run a function called `AddWait` but it adds wait text to all buttons. I tried with `useRef` but things got messy.
Image;

[image: button-not-change]

I did something similar to this with jquery ;

```js
for (let index = 0; index <= 10; index++) {
  $("#app").append(`<span>Hello ${index} </span>
  ===&gt;<button class=click-me>button ${index} </button>
  <br /><br />`);
}

$(".click-me").on("click", function (event) {
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.text());

  $this.text($this.text() + "hi");
  //(... rest of your JS code)
});
```

```html
 <div id="app"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can check react [app](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-matan-3my6w?file=/src/App.js:0-541);

So how can I change only clicked button text?

Comment: You are using same waitText variable in every button so , if waitText value is changed then it gets reflected in each button .

Comment: No wonder, `onClick` you change the text which is shared with all the buttons. When the component re-renders all buttons' texts are changed. You need to adjust your code to use for example a data structure with its text and change the text only of that button.

Comment: You can wrap the spans and buttons inside div and give `key` attribute to div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is save the div with the button into a separate component and then react will change the button text just for that particular component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const CustomBtn = props => {
  const { item, index } = props;
  console.log(item)
  const [waitText, setWaitText] = useState('');
  const waitThreeSeconds = () => {
    setWaitText("wait");
    setTimeout(() => setWaitText(''), 3000)
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <span>Hello {index} </span>
      <button onClick={waitThreeSeconds}>
        button {index} {waitText}
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[...Array(10)].map((item, index) => (
        <CustomBtn item={item} key={index} index={index} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's worked for me and is so brilliant, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [waitText, setWaitText] = useState();
  const [arr,setArr] = useState([
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
    {
      waitText:""
    },
  ]);
  const WaitThreeSeconds = (index) => {
    console.log("hi");
    let temp = [...arr];
    temp[index].waitText = "wait"
    setArr([...temp])
    // setWaitText("wait");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((x, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <span>Hello {i} </span>
          <button onClick={()=>WaitThreeSeconds(i)}>
            button {i} {x.waitText}
          </button>
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check the sandbox code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-pine-ibld0?file=/src/App.js) .
I hope you find it helpful :)